# Unable to link the header files of static library in Cmake ( .h No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, cmake

I use a static library built from [Tensorflow Lite Micro](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro) which produces .a library file (***libtensorflow-microlite.a***). I used another script to extract only the header files of the source files for the library object files. I finally added the .a library and a directory (called ***tensorflow***)  with header files only to my existing project.

In my root CMakeLists.txt file I did the following additions to my last working version: 1- `add_subdirectory(tensorflow)` 2- `target_link_libraries(${APP_TARGET} PUBLIC generic-tflmicro)`.

In the CMakeLists.txt of the headers:

```
add_library(generic-tflmicro "")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
target_include_directories(generic-tflmicro
  INTERFACE
  .
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/third_party/gemmlowp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/third_party/flatbuffers/include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/third_party/ruy
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/third_party/kissfft
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lite/c/
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:lite/c>
)

target_compile_definitions(
  generic-tflmicro
  INTERFACE
  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS TF_LITE_STATIC_MEMORY
  # COMPILE_DEFINITIONS LINUX
  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS TF_LITE_USE_CTIME
)

set_target_properties(
  generic-tflmicro
  PROPERTIES
  LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
  PUBLIC_HEADER "lite/c/common.h"
)

INSTALL (
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lite/
    DESTINATION lite
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")
    
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/*.h )
target_sources(generic-tflmicro
  PRIVATE
  ${SRC}
)

target_link_libraries(generic-tflmicro
    PUBLIC
        libtensorflow-microlite.a
)
```

I can see from the logs that the header files directories are being added to compilation command using `-I` flag like:  `-I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/." -I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow" -I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/third_party/gemmlowp" -I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/third_party/flatbuffers/include" -I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/third_party/ruy" -I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/third_party/kissfft" -I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/lite/c"`.

However when I start the build, I get `fatal error: tensorflow/lite/c/common.h: No such file or directory` although `common.h` is included explicitly in the `-I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw/tensorflow/lite/c"`

Any advice ?

Comment: For being able to include a header via `#include <tensorflow/lite/c/common.h>` you need the option `-I"/home/yahya/Mbed Programs/ozon-2021-fw`.

Comment: Thanks. It did work! You saved my day.